# How to convert PHP code to Twig code?

Tags: php, twig

I am currently trying to add some code to Twig file that I already use with PHP.

There is an online converter from PHP to Twig, but it doesn't do the job. Here is what I get with this converter, converting:

```
 { if($language['code'] == 'bg') {$cur_ = 'BGN';} else {$cur_ = 'USD'; }?>
```

to this:

```
{% if language.code == 'bg' { cur_ = 'BGN' } else { cur_ = 'USD' }}
```

and this:

```
onclick="$('input[name=\'code\']').attr('value', '<?php echo $language['code']; ?>');$('input[name=\'currency_code\']').attr('value', '<?php echo $cur_; ?>');  $(this).parent().parent().submit();"
```

to this:

```
onclick="$('input[name=\'code\']').attr('value', '{{ language.code }} ');$('input[name=\'currency_code\']').attr('value', '{{ cur_ }} ');  $(this).parent().parent().submit();"
```

But I can't understand what exactly should do to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried to do that without using some "online converter" and using  for instance twig docs instead?

Comment: I will keep in mind for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first line, use [`set`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/set.html) to define a variable:

```
{% if language.code == 'bg' %}
    {% set cur_ = 'BGN' %}
{% else %}
    {% set cur_ = 'USD' %}
{% endif %}
```

Better yet, use the [ternary operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators):

```
{% set cur_ = (language.code == 'bg') ? 'BGN' : 'USD' %}
```

For the second, just replace `<?php echo $...; ?>` by `{{...}}`:

```
onclick="$('input[name=\'code\']').attr('value', '{{ language.code }}');$('input[name=\'currency_code\']').attr('value', '{{ cur_ }}');  $(this).parent().parent().submit();"onclick="$('input[name=\'code\']').attr('value', '{{ language.code }}');$('input[name=\'currency_code\']').attr('value', '{{ cur_ }}');  $(this).parent().parent().submit();"
```

Comment: That `set` is invalid though.. `{% if expr %}{% set cur_ = foo %}{% else %}{% set cur_ = bar %}{% endif %}` or `{% set cur_ = expr ? foo : bar %}`

Comment: Could you help me with this php code. It's confusing me. I read online how to convert, but this one seems complicated and I can't make it work.
 
<?php foreach (array('catalog'=>'frontend', 'admin'=>'backend') as $k=>$v ) { ?>
 <label class="btn btn-default <?php if($interface==$k){ echo 'active'; } ?>">
<input type="radio" name="interface" value="<?php e($k); ?>" autocomplete="off" <?php if($interface=="$k"){ echo 'checked'; } ?>> <?php e(${'tab_'.$v}); ?></label>
<?php } // end foreach (array('catalog'=>'frontend', 'admin'=>'backend') as $k=>$v ) ?>

Comment: Make a new question please.